# Optimal blending of gasoline via LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python, cvxpy

[image]

```py
price=np.array([70,60,50]) ## [Super, Regular, Dissel]
cost=np.array([45,35])
x = cp.Variable((2,3)) ## Let x[i,j] denote the barrel of crude oil i-1 to use to produce product j
c=np.array([5000,5000])

profit= cp.Maximize( cp.sum(price*cp.sum(x,axis = 0))- cp.sum(cost*cp.sum(x,axis
= 1)))

const=[]
const.append(x>=0)
const.append(12*x[0,0]+ 6*x[1,0]>=10*(x[0,0]+x[1,0]))
const.append(12*x[0,1]+ 6*x[1,1]>=8*(x[0,1]+x[1,1]))
const.append(12*x[0,2]+ 6*x[1,2]>=6*(x[0,2]+x[1,2]))
const.append(0.5*x[0,0]+ 2*x[1,0]<=1*(x[0,0]+x[1,0]))
const.append(0.5*x[0,1]+ 2*x[1,1]<=2*(x[0,1]+x[1,1]))
const.append(0.5*x[0,2]+ 2*x[1,2]<=1*(x[0,2]+x[1,2]))
const.append(cp.sum(x,axis = 1) <= c)
const.append(cp.sum(cp.sum(x)) <= 9000)

problem = cp.Problem(profit,const)
problem.solve()
print("Status: ", problem.status)
print("The optimal value is", problem.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(x.value)
```

I am very confused with the code why is the revenue portion the number of crude oil used to produce product j. I understand that for the cost, it should use the number of crude oil used for production, but for revenue it is weird to be using it as a way to calculate revenue.

Comment: Hello again, I wouldn't configure it this way. You can declare input vars (crude oil) as x=cp.Variable(2) & output (diesel etc) as y = cp.Variable(3). Then use $y$ for revenue and $x$ for cost in the objective.

Comment: i agree with you thats why i feel that this answer is very misinforming.

Comment: Basically it says $ x_{i,o}$, $i=$ input oils $\{crude 1, crude2 \}$ & $o=$ as output oils, how much of each crude is used to produce a gallon of output. But I don't think question needs that.

Answer (score 2):

The key is in the last sentence: nothing is lost in blending. So the combined amount of crude 1 and crude 2 used to make super equals the amount of super produced, and so on.

Comment: The problem statement magically assumes no refining cost. Not only that, but in real life, the refining cost depends on the type (or blend) of oil used, as well as the output products produced.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, are you saying that textbook problems are not realistic?? I am *shocked*!